# No warning when assigning 'const int' to 'int'

Tags: c

In the subsection 'Simple Assignment' of spec, it has the constraint

- the left operand has qualified or unqualified arithmetic type and the right has arithmetic type

It seems that the following code snippet violates this but `clang -Weverything` doesn't give any warnings. What am I interpreting wrong?

```
const int i = 5;
int j = i;
```

Comment: Qualifying a variable declaration with `const` means that you can’t change the variable; you can only read its value. You’re reading its value.

Comment: How else could you define a constant if you couldn't do this, `const int i = 5;`?

Comment: no assignment in your code !

Answer (score 6):

Integer assignment is done by value. `const int` means that the 4 (or 8) bytes of that `int` are read-only. Assignment just copies the bytes of `i` into another location specified by `j`. This involves reading `i` and writing to `j`, both of which are declared as valid operations.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't perform any assignment, so it does not violate any rules about assignment.

(Your code is a declaration with initialization.)

Answer (score 0):

try i=j; you will see.
gcc give you this: "error: assignment of read-only variable"